# I see 404 when after deploying my react app to github pages

Tags: reactjs, github

I am trying to deploy a 'hello world' react app to github pages but it's not working. instead i see 404.

I follow the steps here - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#github-pages-https-pagesgithubcom

first I created a repo on github called test-react-deploy and cloned it into ~/

than I created a new react app:

```
cd /tmp
npx create-react-app test-react-deploy
cd test-react-deploy
```

than I moved it's content (without the .git folder) into my application repo:

```
cp -r .gitignore node\_modules package.json public src yarn.lock ~/test-react-deploy
cd ~/test-react-deploy
```

I added the following lines to package.json:

```
"homepage": "https://oren.github.io/food",
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
```

and I installed gh-pages:

```
npm install --save gh-pages
```

I pushed everything to github and deploy with:

```
npm run deploy
```

But I see 404 when I go to https://oren.github.io/food

(BTW, I don't have a folder called food in my github pages)

Thanks!

Comment: On GitHub, have you already specified which branch to use for the website? Did you name the repository `oren.github.io`?

Comment: I already have a website running on oren.github.io (html. not react). Now I am trying to have the react website running on /food. Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are creating your gh-page under your test-react-deploy project, so you should see what is happening here: https://oren.github.io/test-react-deploy/

Comment: what's going on here? I want my react app to be deployed to oren.github.io/food...

Comment: You have both https://github.com/oren/food and https://github.com/oren/test-react-deploy, be sure where your are pushing your gh-page

Comment: can you guide me? how do I push the build folder from test-react-deploy repo into oren.github.io/food?

Comment: Maybe you can clone your food project, then copy all your files from the new project and commit|push those changes, remember to install your dependencies

Comment: sorry, i am not following you. I'll eventually deploy the food project but at the moment I am just testing things out so I want to deploy the build folder of test-react-deploy repo to oren.github.io/food. I am probably lacking some knowledge of how gh pages works...

Comment: joseluismurillorios was correct - it looks like the name of the repo is important. If I want to deploy to oren.github.io/food, the repo name should be food and not test-react-deploy. Can someone explain how is it possible to deploy one repo into another?